# Ionic App - Android app build getting stuck on app:mergeDebugResources with no error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic 1 app.

When I enter "Ionic cordova build android" into my command line (git bash), the app build starts and then gets stuck at app:mergeDebugResources with no error.

[here are my logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqvHd.png)

Is there a reason why my app build is stuck without an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally Found a solution.
I went through my directories under '\platforms\android\app\src\main\res' and deleted all directories that did not contain any images.

In addition, when building the app for release I got a message that one of the images were corrupted, so i had to compress that image to a smaller size.